# Animate new "content" with CSS (or Jquery) in handlebars js

Tags: jquery, css, handlebars.js

I'm really new with handlebars.js maybe this is an easy question but I can't figure it out.

Is there a way to animate the template when I send new data using `$('#content').html(html);` ?

Something like a CSS3 transition or jQuery Animation.

I don't know if that is possible, if so, where to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I was downvoted but I think my answer will help others.

What I did was to first hide the `#content` DIV using jQuery's `.hide()` after the handlebar code. When handlerbar is done I re show the div using JQuery's `.show`:

```
function animals(){
    $('#content').hide('fast'); // ANIMATED CLASS REMOVED
    showTemplate(categories_template,animals_data); // Handlbars stuff
    $('#content').show('fast'); // ANIMATED CLASS RE ADDED
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has few to do with handlebar.js ... this is more a general javascript/css question. For instance you could try using [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and jquery: just add a class bounce animated to your div container and you're done.